# How to explore ripple ledger?

Tags: ripple, database, ripple-ledger

I'm running a ripple node on my own server, and try to conduct some analysis to the balance of all ripple accounts. Thus I need to synchronize the ledgers and analyse them.

Currently, my server has been running on the consensus ledger, and I found the browser /rocksdb. However, I don't know how to extract the data from that browser. It there any GUI tool or example code to do so?

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the entire last validated ledger as a giant JSON file if you want to. Be patient, it might take a while. Your server has to have an RPC port open with administrative permissions. You can use this command:

> rippled -q json ledger ' { "ledger_index" : "validated",  "expand" : true, "full" : true } ' > ledger.json

Be patient, this will take awhile. And your server may use a bit more memory and CPU when it's running.

When it's done, you'll have a giant file (about 1.7GB as of right now) called `ledger.json` that contains the entire current ledger. This will contain every account, every XRP balance, every offer, every trust line, every escrow, and so on.